# Error building R package vignette. Error in if (idx > 0) sprintf("default-%s.tex) else "default.tex" : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, r-package, vignette

I am building an R package.

```
==> devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))

Updating package documentation
Writing NAMESPACE
Loading package
.
.
.
Writing NAMESPACE
Updating vignettes
Rebuilding projectR.Rmd
```

I get the following error after this

```
Error in if (idx > 0) sprintf("default-%s.tex", template_versions[idx]) else "default.tex" : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> create_latex_template
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I am not sure what is causing the error. I thought because it calls roxygen2::roxygenize, it may be originating from there but the package doesn't contain this error message. Can someone please guide me in resolving this?

Comment: Are you using `BiocStyle`?

Comment: Yes, @duckmayr.

Comment: What version of `BiocStyle` do you have installed?

Comment: It is version 2.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error from a bug in older versions of `BiocStyle`. As part of the vignette processing in the version you have, the following line is run:

```r
idx <- match(TRUE, version >= template_versions)
```

However, if `version >= template_versions` returns `NA`, then `idx` will also be `NA`. Then the `if (idx > 0)` check throws the error you got.

You can see the commit where they fixed this bug [here](https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocStyle/commit/b0c51e96acf2dddc3934926c131226be2ba63795#diff-b3656b1448a6664365941a3081112c04), by changing the above line to

```r
idx <- match(TRUE, version >= template_versions, nomatch = 0)
```

So, you need version 2.13.1 or later to avoid this bug. One way to do that could be to install from GitHub:

```r
library(devtools)
install_github("Bioconductor/BiocStyle")
```